# Question on PHP cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I came across the snippet below:

```
setcookie('foo', 'v1', time() + 60*60*24, '/');
setcookie('foo', 'v2');
```

- What is the effect of setting 2
  cookies with same name but different
  values?
- Is it common in practice?
- Where is it used?

Comment: Strange indeed (at least for me). I could only *assume* that the original author wanted to create an array: `setcookie('foo[]', 'v1'); setcookie('foo[]', 'v2');` and forgot the brackets.

Comment: @Felix: I see...but what will the above code do "as it is". Will it set 2 cookies or will it overwrite ?

Comment: @Felix Kling: There aren't arrays in cookies. An angle bracket is just another character.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Yes, but PHP will convert this back to arrays, see example 3: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: @Felix Kling: To do so, it needs that the browser sends back all the individual cookies. That will only happen if you give different names to them, otherwise each value will overwrite the previous ones because browsers do not handle arrays. That's why the example adds key names.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Oh you are right. I have not thought that far and just assumed that it is similar to how POST and GET parameters are treated... thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

The above example will simply overwrite the first cookie with the second one. If you want to update a cookie to store a newer value, you can overwrite its value.

Two cookies may have the same name if they were set for different domains or paths. example :

```
<?php 
setcookie("testcookie", "value1forhost", time(), "/", ".domain.com", 0, true);
setcookie("testcookie", "value2forsubdom", time(), "/", "subdom.domain.com", 0, true);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `v1` vs `v2` part makes it look like a trick to detect a cookie handling bug in the browser: if `foo` equals `v1`, the browser did not process the value change.

It'd be interesting to know about the code context.

## Edit

> Will it set 2 cookies or will it
>   overwrite

It depends on where you call the script from. A setcookie() call without a path sets a cookie for current path (where path is an URL path, not the internal file system path). So a call from http://example.com/ would create a single cookie and a call from http://example.com/somewhere/inside/ would crate two separate cookies, one for `/` and one for `/somewhere/inside/`.

Comment: +1 it really looks like that the cookie `foo` should have the value `v1` on all pages and `v2` only on the current page.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not intended. The second cookie call will overwrite the original set cookie. After the first call there is no knowing if browser support is available, as no input from the browser is received when processing a script. A cookie is sent as a HTTP header, and sent back by the browser on consecutive requests.